# Evaluate PHP code only within brackets

Tags: php

I know that `eval()` is not recommended and I am ware of it and I do not need to know that is not a safe method :)

I just need a solution.

I want to evaluate the code of a string coming from the mySQL DB, but I want to apply a filter.

I mean that the `eval()` will have to evaluate the code only if inside brackets `{$code}`.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest putting the code into a separate script and using PHP-CLI to validate the syntax without any execution taking place.

Comment: @DiegoP You don't make it clear whether the entire string will be in curly braces, or whether the curly braces will occur within a larger string, or whether in the latter case different `{$code}` chunks can occur multiple times, or whether you want the `eval()` result to be reinserted into the string variable you've initially assigned the extracted string to.

Answer (score 1):

```
$resultFromDb ='"blah blah blah {echo "Hello world";} blah blah blah';
preg_match('#\{(.*)\}#', $resultFromDb, $matches); // do your own error-checking here
$codeToEval = $matches[1];
eval($codeToEval);
```

Comment: I think it will work only if it finds one variable in the string. What happens when in the string there are many variables, like: <div>{$foo}</div><span>{echo $hello}</span> etc.. Also remember that I do not know which variables will be in the string.

Comment: You didn't mention this in your question.  You can use `preg_match_all()` to find all the matches instead of just the first one.

Comment: @DiegoP.: I realize that you just want a solution, but have you thought about using PHP itself as a template engine, instead of writing your own?  Why write `<div>{$foo}</div><span>{$hello}</span>` instead of `<div><?= $foo ?></div><span><?= $hello ?></span>`?

Answer (score 1):

You maybe could use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) (if you don't need context of previous functions). Example:

```
function runCode( $matches){
    eval( $matches[1]);
}

preg_replace_callback( '~\\{(.*?)\\}~', 'runCode', $text);
```

If you need previous context, the best way would be creating temporary file from `$text` and replacing `{...}` with `<?php .... ?>`...

Answer (score 1):

The use of **preg_replace_eval** may be an option(**preg_replace** with the modifier **e**)

Example:

```
$v='variable';
$i=123;
$s='this is a string';

$string = 'some {$v}  and a instruction {++$i;} and a function-call: {strtoupper($s)} ';

echo preg_replace('@\{([^\{\}]+)\}@e',
                  "$1",
                  $string);
```

returns:

```
some variable and a instruction 124 and a function-call: THIS IS A STRING
```

Comment: It's `preg_replace_callback` .)

Comment: No, I mean preg_replace_eval, it's not a real function, it's a alias for preg_replace() when used with the e-modifier, see the manual for more details.

Comment: http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=preg_match_eval&lang=en&scope=quickref < nothing found, can you provide a link? Why not using preg_replace_callback? It should be optimalized.

Comment: You have to select "online documentation" for the search, then you will find for example http://de.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Ah, I'm used to write constants in upper cased string, writing it as function name (lower case) was confusing. After adding an example +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very dirty solution:

```
$string = 'something {code} echo "hi"; {/code} something else {code} echo "more!"; {/code}';

preg_match_all('/{code}(.+){\/code}/U', $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $match)
  eval($match);
```

I might have misunderstood, maybe this is what you want:

```
$string = 'something {echo \'hi\';} something else {echo \'more!\';}';

preg_match_all('/{(.+)}/U', $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $match)
  eval($match);
```